# How to install latest version of gtk+(3.24.38)

Tags: gtk3

I am developing an application that runs on Windows but not on Linux.

On Windows (MSYS2) `pkg-config --modversion gtk+-3.0` returns `3.24.38`.

On Linux `pkg-config --modversion gtk+-3.0` returns `3.24.33`.

I have tried `sudo apt upgrade libgtk-3-dev` but that does nothing so I am looking for a way to install version GTK `3.24.38` published [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/3.24.38-1ubuntu1) .

I have found build instructions [elsewhere](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/x/gtk3.html) but is that my only option?

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and [*official* flavors of Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *Windows is not Ubuntu, and this is a Ubuntu Q&A site, not SE Unix & Linux*

Comment: My question mentioned my Windows OS bit is about Linux. I have edited the question to make it clearer. I would like to install 3.24.38 on Linux.

Comment: Ubuntu 23.10 (*mantic*) doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *mantic* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 5 October 2023, and isn't on-topic here until release on 12 October 2023.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/mantic-minotaur-release-schedule/34989  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *mantic* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)   *Linux isn't on-topic as already stated, Linux is supported on SE Unix & Linux - this is a Ubuntu Q&A site*

Comment: You're going to have to educate me a bit because I did not mention Ubuntu 23.10. I simply wish to install GTK+ version 3.24.38

Comment: That package is a *mantic* package; Ubuntu *mantic* isn't on-topic on this site until **after** it's release as Ubuntu 23.10.  (`libgtk-3-dev | 3.24.38-1ubuntu1   | mantic          | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x`)  or you could use your own link too (ie. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/3.24.38-1ubuntu1)  instead of my use of CLI enquiries...

Comment: I suspect you might be bitten by the differences between Windows and Linux. Going for the newest is common in Windows, but that approach will break Linux compatibility. None of your Linux users will have 3.24.28 for months until they receive it from a distro. Many won't have it for years until they release-upgrade from older LTS releases.

Comment: Related: [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)